# Arrange list of class type from uncollated to collated manner

Tags: vb.net, linq, list

I have a list of class type with class structure as below:

```
Class MyClass
Public Property ID As Integer
Public Property Details As Object
End Class
```

Now, my list contains items of MyClass type in following manner:

Item1(ID=1,Copy1)

Item2(ID=1,copy2)

Item3(ID=1,copy3)

Item4(ID=2,Copy1)

Item5(ID=2,copy2)

Item6(ID=2,copy3)

Item7(ID=3,Copy1)

Item8(ID=3,copy2)

Item9(ID=3,copy3)

Here, i wanna arrange the same list in collated manner as below:

Item1(ID=1,Copy1)

Item2(ID=2,Copy1)

Item3(ID=3,Copy1)

Item4(ID=1,copy2)

Item5(ID=2,copy2)

Item6(ID=3,copy2)

Item7(ID=1,copy3)

Item8(ID=2,copy3)

Item9(ID=3,copy3)

My list contains thousands of entries in-memory and not finding advisable looping through for the same.

Is there any way to do the same with performance?

Comment: Does the word "LINQ" ring a bell?

Comment: @GertArnold I think yes but cant find clear approach with the same.

Comment: So which approach *did* you find?

Comment: @GertArnold Yes i achieved the same using Linq GroupBy. I have mentioned code in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the same using following Linq GroupBy:

```
Dim oMyClassList As New List(Of MyClass)
For iCopySequence As Integer = 0 To iNoOfCopies - 1 Step 1

    oMyClassList.AddRange(oMyClassOriginalList.GroupBy(Function(v) v.ID).Select(Function(v) v(iCopySequence)).ToList)

Next
oMyClassOriginalList = oMyClassList
```